# Pasar valor de registro afectado en trigger

Tags: mysql

En `MySQL` estoy tratando de hacer un *trigger* que almacene los cambios realizados en una tabla.

Mi tabla principal:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    id INT,
    product VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

La tabla que guardará los cambios:

```
CREATE TABLE saleshistorico (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idchange int NOT NULL,
  old_valor varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  new_valor varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  usuario varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Insertamos algunos registros:

```
INSERT INTO Sales(id, product, quantity)
VALUES
    (100,'Ferrari Enzo',140),
    (200,'Chrysler Plymouth Prowler', 110),
    (300,'Ford Model T Speedster', 120);
```

Luego tenemos el *trigger*:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_sales_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON sales FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.quantity <> new.quantity THEN
        INSERT INTO saleshistorico(idchange, old_valor, new_valor)
        VALUES(id, old.quantity, new.quantity);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

En `idchange` de *saleshistorico* quiero guardar el `id` de la tabla *sales* que se está modificando. Pero al ejecutarlo sale 0 (cero).

```
UPDATE Sales SET quantity = 777 WHERE id = 300
```

Comment: parece que te falto el OLD  =  OLD.id

Comment: Tienes razón @John, recuerdo haberlo probado y no funcionaba, creo que ya estoy quemando neuronas.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: El trigger no te va a funcionar por que no estás indicando `usuario` ,  o deberías darle un valor default ese dato.

Comment: Cierto! es not null, pero en ese caso quería capturar el usuario de la aplicación, no del MySQL.